# SQL: How to delete children table of a children table?

Tags: sql

I got 3 tables, USERS, CHATBOX, IMAGEBOARD. An user can have (0,N) chatbox, a chatbox can have (0,1) imageboard.  I need to delete an user. So I need to delete imageboard before chatbox, and chatbox before USers. What is the request ?!

This is an image of my schema:

[image: Table Schema]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a pattern like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
  -- delete statements here.
END TRY

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

The delete statements will look something like this:
(I don't do mysql much so excuse minor mistakes)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IMAGELIST (
-> ID INT NOT NULL
)

SELECT C.FK_IMAGEBOARD AS ID
FROM CHATBOX C
INTO IMAGELIST
WHERE C.FK_USERNAME = @USERNAME

DELETE FROM CHATBOX WHERE FK_USERNAME = @USERNAME;

DELETE FROM IMAGEBOARD WHERE ID IN
  (SELECT ID FROM IMAGELIST)

DELETE FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME;
```

Comment: You cannot delete from imageboard because those rows are still referenced from the chatbox table (because fk_imageboard still contains the FK value to imageboard).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think this is correct and the FK is from Imageboard to Chatbox.

Comment: @ypercube: but there is a column named `FK_IMAGEBOARD` in the chatbox table. For me this means the chatbox table contains a reference to the imageboard. Which in turn means the imageboard cannot be deleted unless the chatbox is deleted.

Comment: @ypercube: Nice to know I wasn't the only one who thought the description was clear enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

As your chatbox has a reference to imageboard, you cannot delete the chatbox because then the link to the imageboard is lost (of all remaining imageboards you wouldn't know which one belongs to the deleted chatbox.

But you cannot delete from the imageboard table because it is being referenced from the chatbox table. Things would be easier if the imagebox table contained the reference to the chatbox table.

If any imageboard that is no longer used can also be deleted then the following should work:

```
delete from chatbox
where fk_username = 'foobar';

delete from imageboard
where not exists (select 1 from chatbox where imageboard.id = chatbox.fk_imagebox);

delete from users 
where username = 'foobar';

commit;
```

Another option would be to make the foreign keys deferred, then you can delete from the imageboard table before deleting from the chatbox table because deferred constraints are evaluated at commit time not when the actual delete statement is run. Deferred constraints are available in PostgreSQL and Oracle.

Comment: *‘I need to delete **imageboard before chatbox**, and chatbox before USers’* – it's probably `imageboard` that references `chatbox`, not the other way round.

Comment: @AndriyM: look at the linked image. The FK column is part of the chatbox table.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was satisfied with the verbal description and made a wrong assumption. Your answer seems a nice alternative to storing an `imageboard` id before deleting the referencing row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I changed my answer does your reference still make sense?

Comment: @Hogan: not really. I changed mine as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a `on delete cascade` condition to your `users` and `chatbox`tables. That way you don't have to do anything. The DB will delete the entries for you if you delete a user.

You can find an example for MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)